# How to get subpanel cable into wall cavity when going through the top plate isn’t an option

Tags: electrical, subpanel

SER from attic to stud bay, top plate not an option

I’m looking to run a feeder from my main panel to my attached garage for a sub panel. The problem is the wall that I will have the subpanel mounted in is directly between two sister joists. I don’t have an option of going through the top plates, so my question is whether or not I can build a soffit as depicted by the yellow rectangles to allow a chase to bring the feeder from the attic into the stud bay

[image: proposal]

Is there a better option than a soffit? Adjacent wall isn’t an option, and a conduit body won’t allow the needed bend radius

Comment: Although I agree that a soffit can work I have done dozens of jobs over the years with conduit bodies a simple LB it’s a piece of cake to enter a wall. I have done it with ridgid (the hardest) pvc and EMT. It is a simple task of cutting the nipple that is going through the wall to the correct length. If you do build a soffit to the garage you can use nm because a this is the same as running wire inside a wall.

Comment: How about surface mount the panel, EMT conduit going straight up into the drywall, and enter the EMT right above the drywall and on down. Not very posh, but being posh is not the job of a garage.

Comment: Unless you want it to be so for looks, the soffit could simply be a small box covering the area where the wire runs through. It doesn't have to go from corner to corner along this wall.

Comment: Why can't you drill diagonally through the top plate?  Is this a single or double top plate?  This is how my ele ran my subpanel feed though my joists that were under bottom plates  - you just don't want to be at the middle span of the joists.

Answer (score 4):

A soffit is a perfectly good option. Which is as far as we need to go, really.

It's not the only way, but if it suits the need and you like it, then it's as good as it needs to be, and not worse than any others that spring to mind.

Likely it could be smaller and still do the job, unless you have other reasons (functional or aesthetic) for making it as shown.